# Autofac, Console app and UnitOfWork

Tags: console-application, autofac, unit-of-work

I have a console application - Worker - that listens for messages that come in from a queing system, and performs some tasks that involve database access for each of the messages. I use EF 6 to access the MSSQL db and in my implementation I use Unit of work.
My DI container is Autofac - I am new to it -, and I use it to bind among many other things the IUnitOfWork to UnitOfWork.

The problem I have here and I do not know how to deal with is: I want a new UnitOFWork instance for every message, so it cannot be Singleton, but during the same message processing I need the same instance of UnitOfWork, so it cannot be -Instance Per Dependency-.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to using the container directly as shown by @MaDeRkAn's answer you can also use an `Func<Owned<IUnitOfWork>>` instead:

```
containerBuilder
    .RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
    .As<IUnitOfWork>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

public class MessageQueueWorker
{
    private Func<Owned<IUnitOfWork>> unitOfWorkFactory;

    public MessageQueueWorker(Func<Owned<IUnitOfWork>> unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(message)
    {
        using (Owned<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory())
        {
            //access the actual IUnitOfWork with the .Value property
            unitOfWork.Value.DatabaseTable....

            // when the using scope ends the IUnitOfWork and all it's
            // "non shared" dependencies will be disposed
        }
    }
}
```

Hint:
regarding the "non shared" dependencies: these are the ones with the same or shorter scope than `IUnitOfWork` has. A `SingleInstance` injected into `IunitOfWork` would not be disposed, of course.

Comment: This is better solution. Espicially, if you can't reach container like middleware projects.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn `ILifetimeScope` and `Owned` are both defined in the `Autofac` assembly, so i guess one has either access to both or none. I like using `Owned` more because i think the idea is expressed more "concise and to the point".
It's always possible to write a custom wrapper for it, though - in case one wants to make sure that not too much "Composition Root" stuff leaks into all of the projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should register it as [Instance Per Lifetime Scope](http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope)

When message comes, you should begin new Lifetime Scope and resolve your `IUnitOFWork` in there. That's way you will have 1 `UnitOFWork` object in that lifetimescope.

Your register should be like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And you should resolve `IUnitOfWork` like this:

```
var message=GetMessageFromBus();
using(var myLifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var myUnitOFWork = myLifetime.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
}
```